# Dedekind Cut Least Upper Bound Inclusion

Tags: real-analysis

This is a duplicate of questions already asked (which shows others are struggling with this concept as well) - but I don't find the answers rigorous.

When constructing the reals using Dedekind cuts, the least upper bound is proven to be the union of a (possibly infinite) set of cuts. The proof that it is, indeed, the least upper bound is straightforward.

However, I don't see how, given these proofs, that the least upper bound isn't in the union itself.

Say $S=\{(A^\prime, B^\prime)\}$ is a set of cuts, and $t =(A, B) = \bigcup S$. Clearly, we have $s \leq t, \forall s \in S$. However, $t \notin S \implies (A^\prime, B^\prime) \in S$, then $A^\prime \subsetneq A$. But that implies there are elements in $A$ not in any $A^\prime$, contradicting the union.

I know things get dicey with infinite sets of infinite sets - but can someone help clarify?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The least upper bound might be one of the sets we're taking the union of, or it might not. If a set has a maximum, that maximum is the least upper bound, after all.

It might help to consider an example. Consider the set $\{0,\frac12,\frac23,\dots,1-\frac1{n},\dots\}$, represented by Dedekind cuts $S_n=\{x: -\infty < x < 1-\frac1{n},x\in\mathbb{Q}\}$. The least upper bound $\bigcup_n S_n = \{x: -\infty < x < 1,x\in\mathbb{Q}\}$, of course, is the Dedekind cut representing $1$.

Any particular rational $x$ in $[0,1)$ will be in some but not all of these $S_n$ - and, conversely, for any given $S_n$, there are elements such as $1-\frac1{2n}$ not in that particular $S_n$. But it's an infinite union; all we need is some $S_n$ that contains the point, and we can get that by going farther out. None of the individual $S_n$ are equal to all of $S$, and that's fine.

Comment: You meant {0,1/2, 2/ **3**, ...} ?

Comment: I did. That was a midstream change from powers of $2$, that I missed one of the modifications on.

Comment: Hey jmerry. OK - I can see how this would work if we define the infinite union as a limit of finite unions. However, this implies the numbers unions are countable. Your example is, because they are rationals - but we want to take a set of *reals*.

Comment: Trying to put everything into one example isn't a good idea - but OK, we could have an uncountable union. Make those sets $S_r$ for each real $r<1$ and it'll be exactly the same - each rational $<1$ is in some but not all, and each $S_r$ is missing some of them.

Comment: I think I understand now. Its enough to prove that if $S$ has no greatest element, $t$ can't be any of the $S_r$. It's still fuzzy - and weird - since every rational in $t$ came from *some* $S_r$ - but oh well.

Answer (score 1):

You are misinterpreting something here. It is possible that $t\notin S$. The set $A$ is a union of all sets of type $A'$ but it does not necessarily mean that $A=A'$ for some $A'$.

Your statement "there are some members in $A$ which are not in any $A'$" is wrong. The right statement is "for any particular $A'$ there are members in $A$ which are not in $A'$".

On the other hand it is also possible that $t\in S$. It depends on the specific chosen set $S$ (this is always the case when $S$ is finite, but can happen for infinite $S$ also).

---

As a side note, observe that the idea of Dedekind cuts as presented in most modern texts is full of symbolism which sort of creates a big roadblock to understanding. Best would be to study from Dedekind's original pamphlet *Continuity and Irrational Numbers* or its exposition in Hardy's *A Course of Pure Mathematics*. IMHO the construction of reals via Dedekind cuts is much simpler than other approaches (like Cauchy sequence of rationals) as it does not need any new ideas apart from $+, -, \times, /, <, >$ applied on rationals.